# How would I return this "clubName" array to ensure the "choice -1" is used

Tags: java, arrays, serialization

I wanted to pass the "result" of "You Chose : abc" to a return type, so I can then pass it into my serialized method, so that I can then serialize that chosen team. I know how to return an array, but how would I return an array -1 ?

Code snippets are as follows :

```
public class Display{ 
public String[] printGreeting(int choice, String[] clubName) {

    result = clubName;
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 20) {
    System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[choice - 1]); // return the clubName -1
    } 
    return result; // how to declare return statement ?
    }
}
```

Here is my serialize code, not sure how I would pass the array, via an alias or use object ?

```
public class Serialize
{
   public void Serialize() // receive return type from printGreeting();
   {

// how to put object info into files, rather than declare here ?

     try
      {
         FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/home/cg/root/club.ser");
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
     out.writeObject(club);

         out.close();
         fileOut.close();


      System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in C:/tmp/club.ser");
      }catch(IOException i)
      {
          i.printStackTrace();
      }

   }
}
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: You could pass the array into a Serialize constructor and then just reference this.club from within the function.

Comment: As far as returning array-1, I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @JackRyan arrays position start at 0, but humans refer to first position as 1... that what OP means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you declare to return an array of `String[]`:

```
public String[] printGreeting(int choice, String[] clubName) {
    // ↑ here you say this method MUST return an array if Strings
```

What you need is

- assign the user's choice to returned variable
- return just ONE `String`

```
public String printGreeting(int choice, String[] clubName) {
    result = clubName;
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");

    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 20) {
        // assign choice to result
        result = clubName[choice - 1]; 
        // print choice
        System.out.println("You chose: " + result); // return the clubName -1
    } 

    // return the chosen club name
    return result; 
}
```

Actually, I don't know why result is a class attibute (but i cannot see declaration),  what does not make much sense if you want to return it, I will code the method as:

```
public String printGreeting(int choice, String[] clubName) {
    System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"); // ??

    if (choice >= 1 && choice <= 20) {
        choice --; // if choice is valid, get the array position.
        // print choice
        System.out.println("You chose: " + clubName[choice]); 
        return clubName[choice]; 
    } 

    // if the choice is not correct, return null or "" as you want
    return null;
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

> Could anyone advise how I would pass that returned `String` to my `serialize` method, I think I know how to `serialize` it, but not 100% sure on parameter passing.

1. **I don't get exactly what you want to achieve, maybe would be better to rephrase question with your target clear, and your tries.**
2. Serialize (shortly), in `Java` is make an object's attributes convertible to `String`s, then, a `String` either an `String[]` array **does not need to be serialized**.
3. As long as `Display` methods are not `static`, you must create an instance of `Display` to execute as follow:

   ```
   public class Main {
       public static void main(String [] args) {

           // create an instance of Display class
           Display d = new Display();

           // get the needed values to pass to printGreeting method:
           String[] clubs = {"club one", "club two" // put 20 clubs

           // get the index from the user
           Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
           System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
           while (!sc.hasNextInt()) sc.next();
           int choice = sc.nextInt();

           // call the method and get the return:
           String result = d.printGreeting(choice, clubs)

           // then get a serializer and execute method:
           Serialize s = new Serialize();
           s.serialize(result);
       }  
   }
   ```
4. change the method `Serialize.serialize()` to `Serialize.serialize(String)` as follows:

   ```
   public class Serialize
   {
       public void serialize(String club) 
       //                    ↑ receive return type from printGreeting();
       {
            // your serialize code
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks so much, apart from the fact it works, it will improve this newb's understanding.

Comment: Could anyone advise how I would pass that returned String to my serialize method, I think I know how to serialize it, but not 100% sure on parameter passing.

Comment: @DarrenEstcourt , please check my update, also, please answer to point 1 of the update, maybe it's easier you explain what you want to do.... ;)

Comment: I want to serialize the team that has been chosen, so that when my De-serialize method is invoked, I can load the team name chosen. I already know how to serialize an object, but I don't want to declare an object within my Serialized method, I want to pass it as a parameter. Currently I create a new object in my Serialized method via my class which implements Serializable.

Comment: you know how to declare static methods and how to use them? that's what you have to do if you don't want to instantiate the classes

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to return? The club name (String) or the whole array?

It's not clear in your code if result is an array or a String, you simply say `result = clubName`. If it's an array it should be `String[] result = clubName;`, if you want to return a String it should be `String result = clubName[choice -1];`, in that case you have to change the method to `public String printGreeting(int choice, String[] clubName)` and you can `return result;`